# How to locate AND focus objects in artboard from selected layers in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections

In Illustrator, I have hundreds of objects and layers in one file, how can I quickly **locate and focus** objects in the artboard from layers selected in the Layer Panel?

I know one slower way is to use the right most section of the layer to select the object and then looking for transform widget in the artboard:

[image]

But when you have hundreds of objects and the one you are looking for is small, it is hard to spot it. Is there a better way which can focus to the object as well?

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

Proper layer management, locking/hiding objects when not working on them, saving selections.. all these can make things easier.

However, they all need to be something one thinks about while *constructing* a file. After a file is constructed it can be a mess to find minute objects if you haven't been organized from the start.

Comment: Yeah, if I was the one who construct the file, I usually will do what you said; but when you get files from someone else who doesn't bother to organize things, it's a pain to find tiny hidden objects in the artboard...